# How to access to accelerometer sensor of android phone using flutter app?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, accelerometer, sensors

I need to display a **push notification** when my **android phone faced a  motion** using **flutter android application** . How can I do that ?

Comment: There is a beautiful plugin named: Sensors... Check out this link: https://pub.dev/packages/sensors for more guidance...

Answer (score 2):

pubspec.yaml

`dependencies:
  sensors: ^0.4.1+7` (dont forget to install)

file.dart

```
import 'package:sensors/sensors.dart';

accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
  print(event);
});
// [AccelerometerEvent (x: 0.0, y: 9.8, z: 0.0)]
```

Velocity of the device, including the effects of gravity

```
userAccelerometerEvents.listen((UserAccelerometerEvent event) {
  print(event);
});
// [UserAccelerometerEvent (x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)]
```

Also describes the velocity of the device, but doesnt include gravity.

```
gyroscopeEvents.listen((GyroscopeEvent event) {
  print(event);
});
// [GyroscopeEvent (x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)]
```

rotation of device

Hope this helps